# не работает скрипт на js

Tags: json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]друзья, маюсь уже целых 6 часов с этой проблемой, уже все перепробовал...не подскажете что не так?

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', 'parsing_result.json');
x.send();
console.log(x);[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

вот ошибка:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20(2)/ospanel/domains/parser/parsing_result.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: начните с установки веб сервера, например OpenServer

Comment: Вы используете запрос httpRequest, а передаёте файл. file:///

Comment: @Denis640Kb, он ничего не передает, он пытается запустить скрипт напрямую из файла(из каталога\проводника\...), отсюда и попытка браузера перейти на file://, как только автор будет открывать скрипт по url а не как файл - всё у него заработает =)

Comment: да, вместо 'parsing_result.json' нужно указать URL

Comment: всем спасибо, это я невнимательный от слова совсем...как уже сказали я запускал просто как файл)